# Gatsby shows only first rendered svg

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

Gatsby renders only first svg image and applies it to others as well.
When it has to show all of these icons (there is no problem in path) it shows it this way:

https://ibb.co/8PHfXkD

This is my code:

```
import Html from "../assets/skills/html.inline.svg"
import Css from "../assets/skills/css.inline.svg"
import Bird from "../assets/skills/bird.inline.svg"
import Gatsb from "../assets/skills/gatsby.inline.svg"

function Team() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <Html />
        <Css />
        <Js />
        <Vue />
        <Rea />
        <Gatsb />
        <Next />
        <Bird />
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Team
```

This is how I use the plugin:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-plugin-react-svg",
  options: {
    rule: {
      include: /\.inline\.svg$/,
    }
  }
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your SVGs share are sharing the same internal `id` hence it is only displaying the first one. If so, change the `id` of each one to convert them to a unique value.

Comment: the only ID of svgs I have found is <pattern id="pattern0"> inside svg code itself. I have changed them all to be a unique value but after that they just stopped showing.

Comment: The IDs sometimes are used in masks inside the SVG, if you change one, you need to replace the mask accordingly (`#pattern1`, etc)

Comment: once i replaced all ids it worked, thanks!